# How to Make three(or two) extra partitions (other than /home) to store my personal data. while installing Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I am planing to remove my windows completely and planning to install ONLY Ubuntu on my laptop from scratch.

**I want to make 3 different partitions other than the /home ( As it was in windows D: E: F:)**

I already know how to give swap,root,ESP,home partitions,
Can anyone tell how to make 3 more partitions of ext4 format(basically i need to store data on em like i did on windows) and should it be primary or logical and which directory to allot.

*Also if anyone may help me with how windows parition scheme and ubuntu parition schemes are different. I need the theory cuz I am a bit curious.) Thanks!*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Comment: @pomsky No..I read that guide already 2 times, it ddidnt helped me making extra partition and how to give them directory

Comment: What you can do is select manual partitioning, create the partitions you want to use, and then set their mountpoints as the folder locations you want them to appear at, ie `/parts/partition1`, `/parts/partition2`

Ubuntu handles this pretty well, and will generate an fstab that reflects this scheme.

Comment: The way things work differently on Unix vs Windows with regard to interaction with partitions is that Windows follows a multiple root, single level mountpoint system. You have multiple root directories, each in the root of a mounted partition, and they are not mountable or accessible anywhere else. On Unix (this includes Linux) a binding system is used. This means that a partition can be put anywhere, mounted anywhere. I could have a data partition actually appear as though it is a folder inside my ~/Desktop folder. You only ever have one local root.

Comment: @sbergeron What is meaning of parts..is it like i have to make directory as  /home/movies or /root/movies while making partitions undrr the installation

Comment: In the ubuntu installer when doing manual partitioning you can simply put the path that you want a partition to appear at, and it will act like a folder at that location. Say I have a partition with `file.txt` in it's root. You can mount that partition at `/mnt/mypartition/` and then the file will be visible at `/mnt/mypartition/file.txt` as though `mypartition` is a folder inside `mnt`. You don't have to manually create those directories, as the installer generates them for you.

Comment: @sbergeron Yes ..but in the installer after chosing 'Something else' then making swap root and home.. do i have to make new ext4 ..if yes.. what should i chose primary or logical and..then it asks you directory like for home we click (/home) so..what i have to do to make new partition

Comment: Do you have free space for new partitions on the drive?

Comment: Yes ofc my hard disk is 1 TB. I am planning to give home partitoon some what 100 gb and rest i want to make 3 drives

Comment: You should be able to just create partitions in some remaining free space that fit the size requirements you wish. If you want more granular control, enter the live environment and use gparted.